# Discord Bot not running async function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm still really new to using Discord Bots (as in the same 24 hours) but I can't seem to figure out why this async function isn't running, my other `on_message` function is working perfectly fine which I find very confusing.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in')
    print("Username: %s" % (bot.user.name))
    print("Userid: %s" % (bot.user.id))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message): # function doesn't run
    print("function test")
    if message.author.id==bot.user.id:
        return
    if 'foo' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('{0.author.mention} bar'.format(message))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("function2 test") # function does run
    userNames=["foo","bar"]
    if message.author.id==bot.user.id:
        return
    for name in userNames:
        if name in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send('{0.author.mention} use <#754183376621010954>'.format(message))

with open("Token.txt","r") as f:
    bot.run(f.read())
```

I'm also trying to figure out how to find which channel a message was sent in for my second function. So if a user types a message that contains an element in `userNames` it mentions them and sends them a channel.

Comment: Are you executing that code as-is (in which case the second on_message function will overwrite the first, causing the first not to execute) or did you just copy paste the working code alongside the broken so we could compare?

Comment: @Allister I copy-pasted my function that was working and the one that wasn't because my first function was working before, I made some changes to other functions and now my first one won't run.

Comment: Your code runs for me when I comment out the second on_message function. Again I would implore you to make sure you only have one on_message function.

Comment: @Allister can you only have 1 on_message() function? So should I combine them into just a single one?

Comment: You can only have one of any function in Python. Function names are just variable names (see this example https://trinket.io/python/f8c3ff548e ). Combining the functions into a single one will work.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I wasn't really thinking about them having the same name so that the second one would overwrite the first.